# how to change the manifest dll version?

Tags: c#, dll, version, manifest

I have an application that use the version 4.4.0.0 of entity framework, but I would like to use a new one. For that, I add the reference to the new dll, set to true local copy and I try to run my application.

However, I get an error that say that the manifest can't load the version 4.4.0.0.

How can I use a new version of the dll?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the your project properties, you''re likely to be on .Net 4.0. 
In order to use EF5 your project need to be updated to.Net 4.5, use nuget to downgrade/upgrade EF.